# Taylor's expansion in order to study the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

**1 doubt:**

Is it right that $\frac{1}{n^2+n}+o(\frac{1}{n})=o(\frac{1}{n})$? I have thought that it holds since $\frac{1}{n^2+n}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ can be collected in $o(\frac{1}{n})$ since goes to $0$ faster than $\frac{1}{n^2}$, right?

**2 doubt:**
If yes so I am saying that $\frac{1}{n^2+n}+o(\frac{1}{n})=o(1/n)$ that is something that goes to $0$.
If $\frac{1}{n^2+n}+o(\frac{1}{n})$ is the expansion of the $n$-th term of a series, the fact that I have obtained $o(1/n)$ tells me nothing and I have to expand up to another term right? In fact $o(1/n)$ is something that goes to $0$ but this does not imply necessarily the convergence (ex. $\sum 1/n$).

Comment: If by $\frac{1}{n^2+n}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$, you mean asymptotic equivalence, yes, since $\frac1{n^2}=o\bigl(\frac1n\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

With asymptotic analysis, it's quite simple:

If $f(n)=\frac1{n^2+n}+o\bigl(\frac1n\bigr)$, we have $f(n)\sim_\infty\frac1{n^2}$, and the latter converges, so the former converges too.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{n^2+n}=o(\frac{1}{n})$...

Comment: @Sisi : you're right. I had in mind it was $+o\bigl(\frac1{n^2}\bigr)$. I'll remove it in a moment.

Comment: Ok so it is true that I have to expand with other terms to determine the behaviour of the series?

Comment: You only have to determine an asymptotic equivalent, and this is the first non-zero term in Taylor's expansion (for a series with ultimately positive terms).